# I want to transfer bid price from jforex (Dukascopy.com) to a DLL (C++)

Tags: java, c++, dll

I want to transfer Bid Price from jforex (Dukascopy.com) to a DLL (C++).
But at runtime, the price (Bid) is not sent to the DLL, I do not know where is the problem?
This is my code for DLL C++ :

DLL.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
extern "C"
{
__declspec(dllexport)double ExportBid( double BIDS)
{
    return(BIDS);
}
}
```

SendBid.java

This is my code for Jforex (Dukascopy.com)

```
package jforex;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import com.dukascopy.api.*;
import com.dukascopy.api.Library;

public class SendBid implements IStrategy {

    private IEngine engine;
    private IConsole console;
    private IHistory history;
    private IContext context;
    private IIndicators indicators;
    private IUserInterface userInterface;
    public static native boolean CreateSession();

    public void onStart(IContext context) throws JFException
    {
        this.engine = context.getEngine();
        this.console = context.getConsole();
        this.history = context.getHistory();
        this.context = context;
        this.indicators = context.getIndicators();
        this.userInterface = context.getUserInterface();

    }

    public static void ExportBid(double BIDS)
    {
        System.load("C:\\DLL.dll");       
    }    

    public void onAccount(IAccount account) throws JFException {
    }

    public void onMessage(IMessage message) throws JFException {
    }

    public void onStop() throws JFException {
    }

    public void onTick(Instrument instrument, ITick tick) throws JFException{
        double bid =  history.getLastTick(Instrument.EURUSD).getBid();
        ExportBid(bid);  
        console.getOut().println("bid :" + bid);            
    }

    public void onBar(Instrument instrument, Period period, IBar askBar, IBar bidBar) throws JFException {
    }
}
```

Please guide me.

Comment: Where do you think the value should be passed to native code? Your `ExportBid`-method does not attempt to do anything with its parameter.

Comment: Do you already know the JNI, specifically [the oracle documentation about loading and linking native methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#compiling_loading_and_linking_native_methods)?

Comment: How are you determining that the value isn't "sent to the DLL"?

Comment: How can i send bid to dll?